# Why doesnt ResultSet.deleteRow() work with query using Trim() function

Tags: jdbc, h2

Given a simple query such as

"SELECT id, foo FROM Bar",

while iterating a ResultSet, deleteRow() works fine, but if the query is

"SELECT id, TRIM(foo) FROM Bar"

it no longer works:

**The result set is not updatable. The query must select all columns from a unique key. Only one table may be selected. [90127-173]**

Is this a jdbc limitation, or an H2 limitation/bug?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the H2 database, result sets are only updatable if:

- all columns of the result set are from the same table,
- the table isn't a system table,
- all columns of the primary key or any unique index are included, and
- all columns of the result set are columns of that table.

The second query doesn't match the last criteria. This is needed to change the value of a row and column (using `ResultSet.updateX`). I understand you don't actually want to edit the data; however the H2 database doesn't currently make a distinction between the ability to edit the data and the ability to remove the row.